# Rails - Failing to add custom font to my app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

Downloaded the following font https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat and unzipped it. Stuck the otf files in app/assets/fonts.

I have a file called `base.scss` in my stylesheets folder where I have this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "test";
  src: url("/assets/test.otf");
          font-weight: normal;  
        font-style: normal;  
}

.test {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "test";
}
```

And in my `config/application.rb` file is changed to this:

```
module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('/app/assets/fonts')
  end
end
```

However the custom font still is not displaying in text with the `.test` class. What am I doing wrong? I'm using cloud 9 IDE by the way if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

1. Check browser debug/network console to see if the browser is trying to load that font. Maybe server can't send it?
2. Have you restarted server after editing config files?
3. For production purposes change url to asset_url due to asset precompilation. It would be propably necessary to change the:

`url("/assets/test.otf");`

into

`asset_url("test.otf");`